# How to create bootstrap confidence intervals for a gradient boosted machine

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, bootstrap, model

I'm trying to build bootstrap confidence intervals for the predictions of my model, which is a gradient boosted machine.

I understand that this is done as follows:

0. Tune and build the "mean" model
1. Sample the training data with replacement
2. Rebuild the model on the sampled data
3. Repeat steps 1-2 N times
4. Predict onto a given observation N times (once with each model from step 3) and calculate the, say, 5th and 95th percentile to get a confidence interval

On reflection, I'm a bit unsure of the details surrounding step 2. When rebuilding our N models on each bootstrap sample of the training data, should we:

- A. Use the original hyper-parameters, including the number of trees
- B. Use the original hyper-parameters, but first run a cross-validation routine with early stopping to find a revised number of trees which is optimal for the sample
- C. First re-run a full hp tuning routine on the sample, to obtain a fully revised set of hyper parameters that are optimal for the sample, then build the model with these revised HPs

My intuition is the A is most appropriate, but I can see an argument that the original set of hyperparameters are not "optimal" for any given bootstrap sample, and so to generalise the problem most fairly we might need to use method C (at least in theory ... In practice this might be computationally too expensive).

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: gbm = generalized boosted model? Gradient boosting machine? Global business model?

Comment: Apologies Jeremy, it's a gradient boosted machine. I have edited the original post.

Comment: I also edited the title - people scan down the list of questions looking for something they're interested in so the title should include this sort of detail (to increase the probability you get a good answer).

Comment: That depends on whether you tuned the original hyper-parameters or not; if you used defaults, continue to do so; otherwise, if you tuned them, you'll want to re-tune them using the same methodology *inside* each bootstrap iteration, i.e., on the bootstrap sample.

Comment: Thanks jbowman. I'm struggling to understand the soundness of approach A, vs C (which appears to be your recommendation). In my head, A uses the hyperparameters of the original model (obtained through CV HP tuning), and so these give the "construct" of the model - and therefore this feels like the natural approach to carry forward into our N bootstrapped based models. In C, where we re-tune each time, we generalise the approach but not the model. Do you think that's an unfair perspective?

Comment: One way to look at this is that those hyperparameters you used after your initial tuning are only estimates, not known true optimal hyperparameter values.  Those estimates are based upon the data, just like coefficient estimates in, say, a linear regression, or the leaf node estimates in a GBM.  Consequently, your predictions are a function of *estimated* optimal hyperparameters as well as *estimated* leaf node values and optimal tree structures, and the bootstrap should therefore recalculate them as well.